# How to prove this proposition like below?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be locally convex linear topological spaces.
Suppose that $ \{U_{i}: i \in I\}$ is a subbasic system of convex, circled neighborhoods
of zero for the neighborhood system of zero in $X$. Let $ u\colon X\to Y$ be a linear mapping.
Then, $u$ is continuous if and only if given a continuous seminorm $q$ on $Y$, there
exist indices $i_{1},i_{2}, \ldots ,i_{n}$ such that for some $K > 0$

$q(u(x)) < K sup\{p_{U_{i_{k}}}(x): 1\leq k \leq n\}$,

where $p_{U_{i_{k}}}$ is Minkowski functional in $U_{i_{k}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Recall how one constructs a locally convex topology by means of the Minkowski functionals.